# update a part of a varchar column in sybase

Tags: sql, sybase

I have a column in a table which has value

```
    121Z000CH  YY03+ W
```

is it possible using sybase query language to update this column only in the characters 14 to 2 using substring? i.e. i need to replace 03 with some other number say 05.
Currently i'm trying the below statement which is giving me syntax error. Please correct me in this.

```
    update recordtable
    set substring(recordtable.column,14,2) = '05'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use below query for the same -

```
update recordtable
    set column = substring(recordtable.column,1,13)
                 ||'05'||substring(recordtable.column,16)
```

Comment: thanks pratik, just needed to add a small change in it: update recordtable
    set column = substring(recordtable.column,1,13)
                 ||'05'||substring(recordtable.column,16,17)